# jQuery Carousel Next / Previous Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

Here's the [Link to the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hectooorr/sbp76sLc/).

I'm working with a carousel and I want to make the next/previous buttons functional.

I tried adding the following code but it doesn't update the index properly. Any help would be appreciated!

```
$($btnNext).click(function (event) {
     updateSlides(index + 1);
     event.preventDefault();
 }
 $($btnPrev).click(function (event) {
     updateSlides(index - 1);
     event.preventDefault();
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `click` event on those buttons is called, that `index` variable is undefined. There are several different ways of figuring out the index, the method I used in the fiddle was to set an `attribute` on the `slider` and then check it on the `click` events:

```
 function updateSlides(index, paused) {
     $($slider).attr('data-index', index);
     ...
 }

 $($btnNext).click(function (event) {
     var index = parseInt($('.slider').attr('data-index'));
     if(index > $('.slider .content li').length) {
         index = 0;
     }
     console.log('#next', index);
     updateSlides(index + 1);
     event.preventDefault();
 });

 $($btnPrev).click(function (event) {
     var index = parseInt($('.slider').attr('data-index'));
     if(index < 0) {
         index = 0;
     }
     console.log('#previous', index);
     updateSlides(index - 1);
     event.preventDefault();
 });
```

See the updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/sbp76sLc/14/

Comment: I see what you did. Thank you!